# scrollTop: container.offsetTop not moving to the specified container in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I want to move through a list of sentences sequentally.

These sentences are defined in HTML div containers with the class `parallelSentence`.

First I grab all the sentences in a list with `parallelSentences = $( '.parallelSentence' );`

Then choose a sentence from that list specifying its index on the list, with `textContainer = parallelSentences.find( '.source-sentence' ).get( 1 );` for item at position *1*.

Finally move to that sentence container:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: textContainer.offsetTop
    }, "slow");
```

But the above code moves to a higher position than the expected container.

How to move to the sentence container?

In the following code snippet: if I choose the index `0`, It should get the *Hello World* container, index `1`: *Hello* container, index `2`: *How are you?*, so these are the expected locations to move each time but it is currently moving higher than their specified containers.

```js
parallelSentences = $( '.parallelSentence' );

textContainer = parallelSentences.find( '.source-sentence' ).get( 1 );

$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: textContainer.offsetTop - 150
    }, "slow");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta
     name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>

    <body>
 <div id="content">
     <div class="container-fluid py-5">
  <header class="text-center mb-5">
      <h1 id="equilang-item-header" lang="en">Hello World <span lang="es">- Hola Mundo</span></h1>
      <h2> <small class="text-muted">Hello World</small></h2>
      <div class="text-center">
   <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row border-top text-muted pt-4">
   <div class="col-6 border-right">
       <p>
    <a href="/plaintext/14-hello-world/">Main text</a>  by <em><a href="/authors/john-doe-1/">John Doe</a></em>  in <strong>English</strong>.
       </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6" id="translation-title-meta">
       <p>
    <a href="/plaintext/15-hola-mundo/">Translation</a>  by <em><a href="/authors/richard-roe-2/">Richard Roe</a></em>   in <strong>Spanish</strong>.
       </p>
       
   </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
   <p></p>
      </div>
  </header>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-10 col-11-md">
   <div class="row border-top pt-3 mb-5 bg-light">
       <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="fas fa-music fa-5x"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        English
        <button id="btn-play-source" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> EN</button>
        
    </p>
    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        English - Spanish
        <button id="btn-play-source-target" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> EN-ES</button>
        
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        Spanish
        <button id="btn-play-translation" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> ES</button>
        <p class="text-muted text-center">
     Spanish - English
     <button id="btn-play-target-source" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> ES-EN</button>
     
        </p>
        
       </div>
   </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-11 col-10-md">
   <h3  class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">Title</h3>
   <div id="equilang-parallel-title-block">
       <div id="parallelSentence-55-60" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
    <div id="src-55" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
        <ruby>Hello World</ruby>
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
        <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
     Hola Mundo
        </div>
        <p class="border-top pt-3">
     <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines55mp3">
         <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
     </button>
        </p>
        
    </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <h3 class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">Content</h3>
   <div id="parallelSentence-56-61" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-56" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>Hello</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        Hola
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines56mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parallelSentence-57-62" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-57" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>How are you?</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        Como estas?
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines57mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parallelSentence-58-64" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-58" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>I&#39;m good</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        gracias
        <audio class="translation-sentence-audio" src="/media/lines/64.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines58mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parallelSentence-59-63" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-59" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>thanks</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        Yo bien y vos?
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines59mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="playlist-status"></div>

   <div id="audio-player" class="d-flex justify-content-center fixed-bottom invisible">
       <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2">
    <button id="audio-player-pause" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
       </div>

   </div>

      </div>
  </div>
     </div> <!-- container -->

 </div>

 
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get position of element,

Note: This values varies with the window if it is already scrolled, so you can use `window.scrollY` with it to always scroll to position w.r.t to window

```js
parallelSentences = $('.parallelSentence');

textContainer = parallelSentences.find('.source-sentence').get(0);

$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: textContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY
}, "slow");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid py-5">
      <header class="text-center mb-5">
        <h1 id="equilang-item-header" lang="en">Hello World <span lang="es">- Hola Mundo</span></h1>
        <h2> <small class="text-muted">Hello World</small></h2>
        <div class="text-center">
          <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row border-top text-muted pt-4">
          <div class="col-6 border-right">
            <p>
              <a href="/plaintext/14-hello-world/">Main text</a> by <em><a href="/authors/john-doe-1/">John Doe</a></em> in <strong>English</strong>.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6" id="translation-title-meta">
            <p>
              <a href="/plaintext/15-hola-mundo/">Translation</a> by <em><a href="/authors/richard-roe-2/">Richard Roe</a></em> in <strong>Spanish</strong>.
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-10 col-11-md">
          <div class="row border-top pt-3 mb-5 bg-light">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <i class="fas fa-music fa-5x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <p class="text-muted text-center">
                English
                <button id="btn-play-source" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> EN</button>

              </p>
              <p class="text-muted text-center">
                English - Spanish
                <button id="btn-play-source-target" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> EN-ES</button>

              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <p class="text-muted text-center">
                Spanish
                <button id="btn-play-translation" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> ES</button>
                <p class="text-muted text-center">
                  Spanish - English
                  <button id="btn-play-target-source" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> ES-EN</button>

                </p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-11 col-10-md">
          <h3 class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">Title</h3>
          <div id="equilang-parallel-title-block">
            <div id="parallelSentence-55-60" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
              <div id="src-55" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
                <ruby>Hello World</ruby>
                <p>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
                <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
                  Hola Mundo
                </div>
                <p class="border-top pt-3">
                  <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines55mp3">
         <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
     </button>
                </p>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <h3 class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">Content</h3>
          <div id="parallelSentence-56-61" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
            <div id="src-56" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
              <ruby>Hello</ruby>
              <p>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
              <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
                Hola
              </div>
              <p class="border-top pt-3">
                <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines56mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="parallelSentence-57-62" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
            <div id="src-57" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
              <ruby>How are you?</ruby>
              <p>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
              <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
                Como estas?
              </div>
              <p class="border-top pt-3">
                <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines57mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="parallelSentence-58-64" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
            <div id="src-58" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
              <ruby>I&#39;m good</ruby>
              <p>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
              <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
                gracias
                <audio class="translation-sentence-audio" src="/media/lines/64.mp3"></audio>
              </div>
              <p class="border-top pt-3">
                <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines58mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="parallelSentence-59-63" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
            <div id="src-59" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
              <ruby>thanks</ruby>
              <p>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
              <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
                Yo bien y vos?
              </div>
              <p class="border-top pt-3">
                <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines59mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="playlist-status"></div>

          <div id="audio-player" class="d-flex justify-content-center fixed-bottom invisible">
            <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2">
              <button id="audio-player-pause" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->

  </div>



  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) refers to *"the number of pixels from the top **of the closest relatively positioned parent element.**"*

Try using [`getBoundingClientRect().top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) instead, which fetches the offset relative to the *window*.

```
scrollTop: textContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

```js
parallelSentences = $( '.parallelSentence' );

textContainer = parallelSentences.find( '.source-sentence' ).get( 1 );

$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: textContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top
    }, "slow");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta
     name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>

    <body>
 <div id="content">
     <div class="container-fluid py-5">
  <header class="text-center mb-5">
      <h1 id="equilang-item-header" lang="en">Hello World <span lang="es">- Hola Mundo</span></h1>
      <h2> <small class="text-muted">Hello World</small></h2>
      <div class="text-center">
   <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row border-top text-muted pt-4">
   <div class="col-6 border-right">
       <p>
    <a href="/plaintext/14-hello-world/">Main text</a>  by <em><a href="/authors/john-doe-1/">John Doe</a></em>  in <strong>English</strong>.
       </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6" id="translation-title-meta">
       <p>
    <a href="/plaintext/15-hola-mundo/">Translation</a>  by <em><a href="/authors/richard-roe-2/">Richard Roe</a></em>   in <strong>Spanish</strong>.
       </p>
       
   </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
   <p></p>
      </div>
  </header>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-10 col-11-md">
   <div class="row border-top pt-3 mb-5 bg-light">
       <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="fas fa-music fa-5x"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        English
        <button id="btn-play-source" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> EN</button>
        
    </p>
    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        English - Spanish
        <button id="btn-play-source-target" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> EN-ES</button>
        
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        Spanish
        <button id="btn-play-translation" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> ES</button>
        <p class="text-muted text-center">
     Spanish - English
     <button id="btn-play-target-source" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i> ES-EN</button>
     
        </p>
        
       </div>
   </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-11 col-10-md">
   <h3  class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">Title</h3>
   <div id="equilang-parallel-title-block">
       <div id="parallelSentence-55-60" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
    <div id="src-55" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
        <ruby>Hello World</ruby>
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
        <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
     Hola Mundo
        </div>
        <p class="border-top pt-3">
     <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines55mp3">
         <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
     </button>
        </p>
        
    </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <h3 class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">Content</h3>
   <div id="parallelSentence-56-61" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-56" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>Hello</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        Hola
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines56mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parallelSentence-57-62" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-57" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>How are you?</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        Como estas?
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines57mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parallelSentence-58-64" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-58" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>I&#39;m good</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        gracias
        <audio class="translation-sentence-audio" src="/media/lines/64.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines58mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parallelSentence-59-63" class="row py-5 parallelSentence">
       <div id="src-59" class="col-8 source-sentence" style="font-size: 2em">
    <ruby>thanks</ruby>
    <p>
    </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 translation-sentence border-left">
    <div class="p-2 mb-1 text-muted">
        Yo bien y vos?
    </div>
    <p class="border-top pt-3">
        <button class="translation-audio" data-target="stclines59mp3">
     <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="playlist-status"></div>

   <div id="audio-player" class="d-flex justify-content-center fixed-bottom invisible">
       <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2">
    <button id="audio-player-pause" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
       </div>

   </div>

      </div>
  </div>
     </div> <!-- container -->

 </div>

 
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very informative and pointed me in the right direction but using it in combination with `window.scrollY` as suggested in the other answer made it work in other situations, thanks.